# Get Database Value Dynamically Based On the Object Iteration

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, constructor

I have one appId param which I am passing from controller.ts to service.ts

controller.ts

```
appService.removeCache(appId);
```

service.ts

`const DB_CONFIG = { database: correspondAppStore } /`/ database value should come from corresponding appid which is mapped to Store value.

```
const dbmap = { app1: appStore1, app2: appStore2, app3: appStore3 };

constructor() {
    this.getConfig(DB_CONFIG);
}

function removeCache(appId) {
    // Iterate Over dbmap & filter based on appId got from controller file.
    // Got corresponding app value.
    return correspondAppStore;
}
```

I am wondering how will I get the correspondAppStore value & assign it to DB_CONFIG database key as value.
Any help would be really appreciated, since I am not an expert in javascript & typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Object can be iterate.

```
const dbmap = { app1: 'appStore1', app2: 'appStore2', app3: 'appStore3' };

for (let key of Object.keys(dbmap)) {
  let dbmapName = dbmap[key];

  DB_CONFIG.database = dbmapName;
}
```

Comment: But DB_CONFIG is already declared in service.ts file. So how can we assign the value.

Comment: This answer could use a more detailed explanation since the questioner is not an expert in javascript or typescript.  Please explain your code.

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).